# What size should power wires be to run big appliances?

Tags: electrical, wiring

Most of this apartment has what is 1.5 mm or 2 mm wires through the walls and sockets. I think 1 mm is like 18 AWG so I imagine 2 mm to be close to 16 or 14 AWG. Appliances here are 240v (not U.S.). Take for example, a microwave needs 900 watts, a PC is like 600 watts and home theater is 200-500 watts, washing machines are like 18 amps. But I'm stuck with 2 mm wires that go into the socket (mains maybe thicker), is that okay?

Answer (score 2):

In the UK,

```
Copper                  Circuit
Wire size      Breaker  Type        Example
-------------  -------  ------      -------------------
1 or 1.5 mm²   6A       radial      lighting circuits.  
2.5 mm²        16A      radial      immersion heater.   
2 x 2.5 mm²    32A      ring-final  13A sockets.   
6 mm²          32A      radial      7 kW electric shower, cooker.  
10 mm²         40A      radial      9 kW electric shower.
```

A 2 mm² wire is insufficient for a 18A load in the UK. I believe some countries push the limits further - I'd check local regulations.

In the UK, you also have to downrate wire (i.e. reduce breaker size in amps) depending on how the cable is installed and on its length.

```
            Current Ratings in amps

                     In       Clipped to
Wire Size  In Wall   Conduit  Surface  
---------  -------   -------  -------
  1 mm²       11       13       15
  1.5 mm²     14       16.5     19.5
  2.5 mm²     18.5     23       27
  4 mm²       25       30       36
  6 mm²       32       38       46
  10 mm²      43       52       63
```

Comment: Okay I just double checked, here most devices are around 10A 240V, and I asked an electrical store selling cables and they said I need 3mm wires or else TVs won't work. But of everything is 10A wouldn't that make them work with 2mm or less?

Answer (score 1):

14AWG is 2.08 mm<sup>2</sup>.  In North America this is statutorially limited to 15A, but *other than that*, is rated 20A for 60C terminations, or 25A for 90C terminations.  That means in specialized applications with special terminations, it is good to those currents (though it will make that temperature, and 60C is scalding.)